# Kalanchoe leaves developing brown spots

Tags: kalanchoe

My Kalanchoe plant leaves have developed brown/balck spots on them. Although fresh leaves are coming the old leaves have started falling by the handful. Any tips what it might be causing it and how I can take care?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's an insect of some sort on one or two of the leaves which cannot be seen clearly; you may have a case of scale insect infestation, because the one I can see clearly looks like a little greyish coloured shield on one leaf. Check the underside of the leaves too, as well as the stems, with a magnifying glass if necessary, to determine whether there are other insects on there such as aphids, and carry out the appropriate treatment as recommended in this link https://homeguides.sfgate.com/kalanchoe-pests-61103.html according to what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Its looks like either scale infestation or black spot. I have washed the leaves with alcohol and scraped off the brown scales. Fingers crossed now. Should I go ahead and remove all leaves with black spots as well?